# clock_gettime on Raspberry Pi with C

Tags: c, timer, timing, raspberry-pi

I want to measure the time between the start to the end of the function in a loop. This difference will be used to set the amount of loops of the inner while-loops which does some here not important stuff.

I want to time the function like this :

```
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define BILLION 1E9

float hz = 1000;
long int nsPerTick = BILLION/hz;

double unprocessed = 1;
struct timespec now;
struct timespec last;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &last);

[ ... ]

while (1) 
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now); 

    double diff = (last.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec );

    unprocessed = unprocessed + (diff/ nsPerTick);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &last);


    while (unprocessed >= 1) { 
            unprocessed --;
            DO SOME RANDOM MAGIC;
            }
    }
```

The difference between the timer is always negative. I was told this was where the error was:

```
    if ( (last.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec)<0) {
         double diff = 1000000000+ last.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec;
         }
    else {
         double diff = (last.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec );
    }
```

But still, my variable difference and is always negative like "-1095043244" (but the time spent during the function is a positive of course).

What's wrong?

Comment: Yup, the logic is just back-to-front. If you take a count of the number of ms elapsed at two points in time, the elapsed ms will be lower the first time you call it. If you then subtract the higher number from the first (1stTime - 2ndTime) you'll get a negative number, simply put. 

As suggested below, the correct way is to do 2ndTime - 1stTime = elapsedTime

Comment: Im Sorry .. you are right : I messed it up during the "debugging". But Problem stays the same. It's negative agian.!

Comment: okay, no worries. It may help others to assist you if you edit the original question to indicate which variable is being subtracted from which.

Comment: @user2037819 you can't just subtract the nanosecond member, it's just the number of nanoseconds after the second, it goes from 0 up to 1 second (0 - 999999999 nanoseconds). You'll need to convert the number of seconds (the tv_sec member) to nanoseconds and add that too.

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue is that you have `last.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec, which is the wrong way round.

`last.tv_nsec` is in the past (let's say it's set to 1), and `now.tv_nsec` will always be later (for example, 8ns later, so it's 9). In that case, `last.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec` == 1 - 9 == -8.

The other issue is that tv_nsec isn't the time in nanoseconds: for that, you'd need to multiply the time in seconds by a billion and add that. So to get the difference in ns between now and last, you want:

```
((now.tv_sec - last.tv_sec) * ONE_BILLION) + (now.tv_nsec - last.tv_nsec)
```

(N.B. I'm still a little surprised that although now.tv_nsec and last.tv_nsec are both less than a billion, subtracting one from the other gives a value less than -1000000000, so there may yet be something I'm missing here.)

Comment: Im Sorry .. you are right : I messed it up during the "debugging". But Problem stays the same. It stays negative.! –

I print diff after the calculation with "printf ("Diff: %d,diff);"
And it returns " -1090873500"

Answer (score 1):

I was just investigating timing on Pi, with similar approach and similar problems. My thoughts are:

You don't have to use double. In fact you also don't need nano-seconds, as the clock on Pi has 1 microsecond accuracy anyway (it's the way the Broadcom did it). I suggest you to use gettimeofday() to get microsecs instead of nanosecs. Then computation is easy, it's just:

```
number of seconds + (1000 * 1000 * number of micros)
```

which you can simply calculate as unsigned int.

I've implemented the convenient API for this:

```
typedef struct
{
    struct timeval startTimeVal;
} TIMER_usecCtx_t;

void TIMER_usecStart(TIMER_usecCtx_t* ctx)
{
    gettimeofday(&ctx->startTimeVal, NULL);
}

unsigned int TIMER_usecElapsedUs(TIMER_usecCtx_t* ctx)
{
    unsigned int rv;

    /* get current time */
    struct timeval nowTimeVal;
    gettimeofday(&nowTimeVal, NULL);

    /* compute diff */
    rv = 1000000 * (nowTimeVal.tv_sec - ctx->startTimeVal.tv_sec) + nowTimeVal.tv_usec - ctx->startTimeVal.tv_usec;

    return rv;
}
```

And the usage is:

```
TIMER_usecCtx_t timer;
TIMER_usecStart(&timer);

while (1)
{
    if (TIMER_usecElapsedUs(timer) > yourDelayInMicroseconds)
    {
        doSomethingHere();
        TIMER_usecStart(&timer);
    }
}
```

Also notice the gettime() calls on Pi take almost 1 [us] to complete. So, if you need to call gettime() a lot and need more accuracy, go for some more advanced methods of getting time... I've explained more about it in this [short article about Pi get-time calls](http://yosh.ke.mu/article/raspberry_pi_getting_time)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know C, but if it's a timing issue on a Raspberry Pi it might have something to do with the lack of an RTC (real time clock) on the chip.

Comment: No, the real time clock serves a different purpose: keep the system on sync with the current time. You don't need a RTC to measure a time increment, just [hi-res] counters from the system.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing `last.tv_nsec - now.tv_nsec` in a double.

If you look at the documentation of [`time.h`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/time.h.html), you can see that `tv_nsec` is stored as a long. So you will need something along the lines of:

```
long diff = end.tv_nsec - begin.tv_nsec
```

With that being said, only comparing the nanoseconds can go wrong.  You also need to look at the number of seconds also.  So to convert everything to seconds, you can use this:

```
long nanosec_diff = end.tv_nsec - begin.tv_nsec;
time_t sec_diff = end.tv_sec - begin.tv_sec; // need <sys/types.h> for time_t
double diff_in_seconds = sec_diff + nanosec_diff / 1000000000.0
```

Also, make sure you are always subtracting the end time from the start time (or else your time will still be negative).

And there you go!